# Can I add a click event to a text span?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a large text view that I am styling with a SpannableStringBuilder. I want to be able to assign custom click event handlers to certain spans of text. For example, if I click a superscript character I want it to pop up a toast with some information about what the superscript references. So far I have found linkify which helps to make regular expression type of things like emails and phone numbers launch appropriate activities. What I want to be able to do is define a span and its styling and assign a click handler to it. I haven't found anything built in that supports this kind of functionality and so I'm asking for anyone with a fresh idea of how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is for you to take a look at the [Android source code](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/text/util/Linkify.java;h=79ecfbda0160a6dfda6c302ec79f14af6a18048a;hb=54b6cfa9a9e5b861a9930af873580d6dc20f773c) for the `Linkify` class and see how that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at extending ClickableSpan. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html

URLSpan which is the span used to Linkify, is an example implementation of ClickableSpan.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan.html